# Access. Not work Edit button with comboboxes

Tags: vba, ms-access, combobox

There are cascading combo boxes with dependencies. Each combo box carries the values of one table. After all selections of values, add them to one pivot table.

The problem appeared with the edit button, which should take a row from the pivot table and put the values back into the combo boxes. With my code, combo boxes remain empty. (the textbox is filled with this) Any ideas how to fix the code?

```
   Private Sub btnAdd_Click()
    'add data to table

    CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO toolList(numberTool, roughFinish, application, dim, tool, holder, h, f, s, offsetR, d, toolLife, corNumber, pictureSource, dms) " & _
    " VALUES('" & Me.cboNumberTool.Column(1) & "','" & Me.cboRoughFinish.Column(1) & "','" & Me.cboApplication.Column(1) & "','" & (Me.txtLabelDim.Caption & " " & Me.txtDim) & "','" & Me.cboTool.Column(1) & "','" & _
    (Me.cboHolder.Column(1) & " " & Me.cboMmaster.Column(1) & " " & Me.cboCollet.Column(1) & " " & Me.cboShrink.Column(1) & " " & Me.cboStrshank.Column(1)) & "','" & _
    Me.txtH & "','" & Me.txtF & "','" & _
    Me.txtS & "','" & Me.txtOffsetR & "','" & Me.txtD & "','" & Me.txtToolLife & "','" & Me.txtCorNumber & "','" & Me.txtPictureSource & "','" & Me.txtDms & "')"

    'refresh data in list on form
    ToolListsub.Form.Requery  
End Sub


Private Sub btnEdit_Click()
'check whether there exists data in list
If Not (Me.ToolListsub.Form.Recordset.EOF And Me.ToolListsub.Form.Recordset.BOF) Then
    'get data to text box control
    With Me.ToolListsub.Form.Recordset
        Me.cboRoughFinish = .Fields("roughFinish")
        Me.cboApplication = .Fields("application")
        Me.txtDim = .Fields("dim")
        Me.cboNumberTool = .Fields("numberTool")
        Me.cboTool = .Fields("tool")
        Me.cboHolder = ""
        Me.cboCollet = ""
        Me.cboMmaster = ""
        Me.cboShrink = ""
        Me.cboStrshank = ""
        Me.txtH = .Fields("h")
        Me.txtF = .Fields("f")
        Me.txtS = .Fields("s")
        Me.txtOffsetR = .Fields("offsetR")
        Me.txtD = .Fields("d")
        Me.txtToolLife = .Fields("toolLife")
        Me.txtCorNumber = .Fields("corNumber")
        Me.txtPictureSource = .Fields("pictureSource")
       End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: are the population lines being hit, or are the eof, bof conditions met?

Comment: yes, all conditions are met

Comment: Have you checked that these lines, like `.Fields("roughFinish").value` have values?

Comment: Yes, I checked. nothing has changed. I first fill out the PivotTable with the same combo boxes. Combobox takes the value of a table (not a pivot table). As I understand it, I have to write a cycle in which I find the value and compare it with the original combo box table ... But I don’t know how yet. Is there any thoughts?

Comment: Are comboboxes RowSource a lookup with alias? Is value placed into combobox also an item in combobox RowSource?

Comment: no. That is the problem. RowSource cboRoughFinish (example): SELECT roughFinish.ID, roughFinish.Value FROM roughFinish. After that I add values ​​from comboboxes to the pivot table. 
Now I need to return the values ​​from the pivot table back to comboboxes. To do this, I need to take the value from the pivot table and compare it with what the combo box gives. I do not know how(

Comment: I added the add button code in the main post. You can see how adding a pivot table from combobox

Comment: You would need to add to the roughFinish table, then `.requery` it's contents.  Look at indexing the values so no dupes and handle the error or run a quick `dlookup` or `dcount` to check and then do a sql append and `.requery`

Comment: The advice is very efficient. Thank. But unfortunately, I do not have enough experience to implement it. Can you help me. At least something for an example in my case.

Comment: Thank! Long understood, but it turned out in the end. Here is the code, someone can come in handy Me.cboRoughFinish = DLookup("ID", "roughFinish", "Value = '" & .Fields("roughFinish") & "'")

Answer (score 0):

Thank! Long understood, but it turned out in the end. Here is the code, someone can come in handy Me.cboRoughFinish = DLookup("ID", "roughFinish", "Value = '" & .Fields("roughFinish") & "'")